# Is there a need to mention page numbers from a book in APA 6?

Tags: citations

I am citing some books in me work. Normally there referenced from google scholar are without page numbers, see below. My question is with the APA-6  method should I add the page number to this kind of quote?

***Makhlouf, A. S. H., & Aliofkhazraei, M. (2015). Handbook of Materials Failure Analysis with Case Studies from the Oil and Gas Industry: Butterworth-Heinemann.***

Comment: Independently of APA's (or any other style's) requirements, you should provide enough information for the reader to find whatever you're referring to. I get annoyed when a paper invokes a theorem from some book, gives a reference to the book, but doesn't tell me where in the book to find that particular theorem. (I get even more annoyed when it turns out that the book doesn't contain that theorem but rather another one that's based on the same idea and therefore counts as "the same" in the author's imagination.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

APA 6 seems clear on this: you should include the page numbers if it is relevant to a paragraph or chapter or you are directly quoting text, see the image (source https://libguides.library.usyd.edu.au/c.php?g=508212&p=3476096):

[image]